# How do I run my app on real iPhone? (i have a certificate from my coworker)

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5, iphone-developer-program

So I've been running my app in the simulator, but now it's time to test it on a real device. One of my coworkers sent me a certificate, which I installed. I selected this developer in **Code Signing Identity** menu, but when I try to build it tells me that **No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity were found**.

What now? Should I request something else from him?

We're in different time zones and I'm losing lots of time getting a reply from him.

Comment: you have to select provisioning profile also

Comment: tell your coworker to send .p12 file of certificate, and your device id should be register in that certificate.

Comment: Already installed the .p12 certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process can be sometimes quite complicated. I suggest you to take easier way to do it, which could be done directly in xcode.

Ask your friend to export his developer account from his computer and import it on yours. You can export account from xcode doing those steps:
1. Open xcode.
2. Open xcode's main preferences.
3. Select account for export, click on "option" button below and choose export account.

After importing, setting build settings and adding your device to development list you should be able to test on it.

Answer (score 0):

For building app in device you need two things:
1. Certificate
2. Provisioning profile which should be linked with above certificate.

Please tell your coworker to send provisioning profile that include given certificate.